# DLL TeamFoundation error with VS2015

Tags: dll, tfs, build, visual-studio-2015

I try to run a project built with tfs2013 and vs2013.

All of my colleagues can execute the build of this project but not me (I'm on vs2015).

I understood that the problem came from different TeamFoundation dll (presented in the GAC for vs2013 and placed in c: \ program files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 \ Common7 \ IDE \ CommonExtensions \ Microsoft \ TeamFoundation \ Team Explorer to vs2015 )
There is also a problem with the workspace:
vs2013 = c: \ Users \ Username \ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ Team Foundation \ 5.0 \ Cache
vs2015 = c: \ Users \ Username \ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ Team Foundation \ 6.0 \ Cache

What can i do if i want to execute this build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide the detail error message when you built your project? Did you mean VS2015 can't found the dll in your project?

According to your infomation, the dll in GAC won't be check in  souce control. You can view them in the **references** of the solution. And also it won't affect your build.  However, if the project referenced some Team Foundation dll or 3rd part dll, you may got the error XX.dll can't be found in your project when using VS2015.

A workaround for your situation, create a folder under the solution and add the Team Foundation dll  or 3rd part in the folder. Check them in the source control,remember to edit the build definition to add the folder in source settings. Then you can queue the build sucessfully.

Moreover, `c: \ Users \ Username \ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ Team Foundation \ 6.0 \ Cache` means the cache of TFS. `5.0` stands for TFS2013 and `6.0` stands for TFS2015. This should have no effect on the build result. It just mean you are using TFS2015 instead of TFS2013.